# Zipping ticklines does not allow to change their properties

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.4

I was trying to reduce my code footprint to make it more readable when I stumbled around an odd result. If I run the following code:

```
y1 = np.linspace(1,1000)
y2 = np.linspace(10,1)

c = ["b","g"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(y1, c[0])
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(y2, c[1])

for tl in ax.yaxis.get_ticklines():
    tl.set_color(c[0])

for ts in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels():
    ts.set_color(c[0])
```

I get the following output:

[image]

However, when I try to zip this to reduce the amount of code using the following:

```
for t in zip(ax.yaxis.get_ticklines(),ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    t[0].set_color(c[0]),t[1].set_color(c[0])
```

[image]

All of the ticklabels change but only some of the ticklines (those that do not change are marked in red). Is there some reason why zipping ticklines results in changes in only some of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, there are twice as many `ax.yaxis.get_ticklines()` than there are `ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()`, so zip just stops before painting them all, while individual loops are fine.

This behaviour of `zip` is explained in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).